# Is there an option to set "," as default decimal point for axis labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, axis-labels

When making a graph, `ggplot2` has a lot of sensible defaults for scales that require extra work when trying to achieve the same result using `scales`.

An example:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

Note that this plot has one digit behind the decimal mark.

However, I live in the Netherlands and we're used to using a comma as decimal mark. This is easily done within `scale_x_continuous`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))
```

What bugs me about this solution is that this also increases the number of digits: there's an extra, rather unnecessary, 0 at the end of each label. Of course, this can also be solved within `scales::label_number()`, by setting `accuracy = 0.1` but that requires iteration (plotting and re-plotting to set the more sensible number of digits).

Is there an option to fix the default decimal mark used by ggplot? I'm looking for a solution where

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

returns the same plot as

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(
    big.mark = ".", 
    decimal.mark = ",",
    accuracy = 0.1
  ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key seems to be that `format` (from base R) and `scales::number` use different rules. We can revert to using `format` ...

```r
myf <- function(x, ...) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", ...)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = myf)
```

If you want to make these labels the global default I think you can do this:

```r
scale_x_continuous <- function(..., labels = myf) {
  do.call(ggplot2::scale_x_continuous, c(list(...), labels = labels))
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution to set this for all scales (`scale_y_continuous()`, `scale_fill_continuous()`, etc.) simultaneously? I tried `continuous_scale <- function(..., labels = myf) do.call(ggplot2::continuous_scale, c(list(...), labels = labels))` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you only have to do it once in a session it shouldn't be so bad ... it would be possible to cook something up by looping over strings and using `assign`, but ugh ...

Answer (score 4):

Not specific to `ggplot2` but you can set the output decimal point character globally using `options(OutDec = ",")`.

From the help page:

> OutDec: character string containing a single character. The preferred
> character to be used as the decimal point in output conversions, that
> is in printing, plotting, format and as.character but not when
> deparsing nor by sprintf nor formatC (which are sometimes used prior
> to printing.)

```
library(ggplot2)

options(OutDec= ",")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ritchie! I'm accepting Ben's answer because it's a ggplot2-specific solution but this is very helpful too

Comment: Also, there doesn't appear to be a global thousand separator parameter that can be passed to `options()`.

Answer (score 3):

A more general solution is to write a `{scales}` compatible labelling function `label_format()` that calls `base::format()` under the hood, and then to make a specialized version with the Dutch punctuation conventions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

# Use base::format as a {scales}-compatible labels function
label_format <- function(...) {
  function(x) do.call(format, c(list(x = x), list(...)))
}

# Specialized version for Dutch punctuation
label_format_NL <- function(...) {
  label_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", ...)
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_format_NL())
```

If you don't like having to specify the labels for every axis, you can override `ggplot2::continuous_scale` like this e.g.

```
continuous_scale <- function(...) {
  do.call(
    ggplot2::continuous_scale, 
    c(list(labels = label_format_NL()), list(...))
  )
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Personally, I'd use the explicit `scale_AESTHETIC_continous(labels = label_format_NL())` since that keeps your changes localized. Overriding `options()` or `continuous_scale()` is the moral equivalent of global variables, not recommended.

Comment: this is pretty similar to my answer except that your `label_format` function is prettier ...